# How do you convert little Endian to big Endian with bitwise operations?

Tags: endianness, instruction-set, x86

I get that you'd want to do something like take the first four bits put them on a stack (reading from left to right) then do you just put them in a register and shift them x times to put them at the right part of the number?

Something like

1000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0000 1011

Stack: bottom - 1101 - top
shift it 28 times to the left

Then do something similar with the last four bits but shift to the right and store in a register.

Then you and that with an empty return value of 0

Is there an easier way?

Comment: Left-shift `1101` by 28 bits? That's not how you change the byte order... I think you're changing the nibble order (is that even a term?) instead of the byte order...

Comment: Check this out http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=292902

Comment: Thx, I think I was a little confused on the definition.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is. Check out the [_byteswap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3140177.aspx) functions/intrinsics, and/or the [bswap](http://siyobik.info/index.php?module=x86&id=21) instruction.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this way..
For example 
I/p : 0010 1000 and i want output 
      1000 0010

input store into a variable x
      int x;
      i = x>>4
      j = x<<4
      k = i | j
      print(K) //it will have 1000 0010.